# variable of field declared void error when trying to use object of custom class

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have this header file in my project:

```
#ifndef COMMONINCLUDES_H
#define COMMONINCLUDES_H

#include "utilities.h"
#include "textOutput.h"
#include "game.h"

class Player
{
public:

    int score;
    int poX, posY;
};

#endif // COMMONINCLUDES_H
```

And then in another header file I have

```
#include <commonincludes.h>

void turn(Player *currplayer, int mapSize);
```

and matching function in it's own cpp file. I'm getting a variable of field declared void error at the line of the function prototype, and an error saying 'Player' was not declared in this scope despite including the header file with it. Looking through a bunch of other threads here about the error I haven't found one that was isn't for code all in one file or caused by some error I've ruled out. I know I did something like this before and got it to work but I can't figure out what I'm doing differently this time around.

I've also that moving the class definition (copy paste so I know I'm not changing anything with the class definition) to the header file "utilities.h" which is included in the above header file makes it work...

If that's not enough to go off of let me know and I'll  pull more to include.

Comment: [Unable to duplicate](http://ideone.com/pHxQxN). Recommend [mcve]. Include the complete and verbatim error message text.

Comment: What is the name of "another header"? The one that has `turn` in it.

Comment: It's in the game.h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have circular header inclusion. `game.h` includes `commonincludes.h` and `commonincludes.h` includes `game.h`. Your include guards break the infinite inclusion cycle, but they break it at the point where `Player` remains undeclared at the point of `turn` declaration.

Judging by what you posted so far, there's no need for `#include "game.h"` in `commonincludes.h`. What it is doing there?

P.S. Use `#include "..."` for including your own header files. The `#include <...>` syntax is for standard headers.

Comment: Hmm ok, I see. I was thinking I'd need to call of the functions i had in game.cpp from other cpp files so I had the header for game in commonincludes so it could be one of the things everything that got that had access to. But actually now that I think about it more I'm not going to need that and I do see where that's a problem now. Thank you.